# Excel Userform Image Drag for a simple game

Tags: excel, vba, userform

[image: Image1]

Hi everyone. I am trying to create a simple drag and drop game where the player should be able to drag an Image Control to a Specific location in a UserForm.

I have tried to look around the net without getting a specific answer to my issue.

The procedures available for an image control doesn't seem to do anything:

```
Private Sub Image1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

End Sub
```

Any advise?

Comment: How about using `Private Sub Image1_BeforeDragOver(....` instead? http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-454.html

Comment: hi, can you show me how the guide can be used on my project? sorry this is the first time i have encountered this beforedragover event and i cannot find anything relevant for excel2013 in google.